# Unable to retrieve bulk records using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table in MySQL with the structure:

```
id int(10) PRIMARY,
app_no varchar(255)
```

and `INDEX appno_index` of type `BTREE` on field app_no

Now this table has 900000 + records in it. I am using CodeIgniter model to list the records.
My query for the listing of records in CodeIgniter is

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT id, app_no FROM `app_no` USE INDEX(appno_index)");
```

But MySQL throws error like this.

**Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes) in C:\wamp\www\~\system\database\drivers\mysql\mysql_result.php on line 162**

How do I optimize my query using anything so that the page displays all the records?

Comment: It looks like your PHP process can only use 128 MB memory at a time.  Your 900,000 records are too big to fit in memory (presumably, the average record size is around 128 bytes).  This is OK; no-one is going to look at all 900,000 records, so you really don't want your page to display all 900,000 records or PHP to get all 900,000 records into memory.  If you think you do need them all, you're designing your application ... sub-optimally; the database should be where you do the query processing, not the application.

Comment: yes certainly I do not want to display 900000 records on a single page. If 50 records per page are displayed then its cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is way too many records to be displaying on a single page.

Look into using CodeIgniter's [Pagination Library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html) instead.

Comment: thank you. It works but still looking for some other alternative. because i am already using jquery.dataTable.min.js for sorting, searching and pagination.

Comment: If you're using jQuery DataTables, utilize the [`sAjaxSource` parameter.](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/ajax.html). Fetch the content this way and serve JSON. DataTables should be able to take care of the rest.

Comment: that didnt work. I used hybrid solution - php pagination at controller side and jquery pagination at view side.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `LIMIT 0 , 30` to the end of the query, where the first `0` is the offset (where to start fetching rows) and the second `30` is the amount of rows to fetch.

Comment: but then it fetches only 30 records. I want to display all records no matter if i have to using paging.

Comment: @user1730542 so you want to display all 900000+ rows on a single page? If my calculations is correct, 900000 rows in that table is about 223MB of data, you would have to increase the php memory size to be able to show all those records, and it will most likely choke the server either way if it's gonna be a live site with a couple of visitors visiting at the same time. I would recommend doing multiple pages, `LIMIT 0 , 30` for the first page, `LIMIT 30 , 30` for the second and so on.

Comment: yes its k for me to use paging. I am already using jquery.dataTables.min.js to perform search pageing and sorting. But when the query is fired SELECT * FROM  at that time the database will return 900000 records and if i use limit 0,30 then it will display only 30 records. To again specify LIMIT 30,60 i need to fire another query in CodeIgniter Model so for 900000 records it  is impossible. I am looking for a solution to optimize/modify my query so that it returns the data which mysql server can hold and jquery can display

Comment: when you using Jquery for these amount of records, it take more time to render in front end.. paging should be in PHP or use AJAX instead.

Comment: @Prasath AleHow do i use paging in php when jquery is already doing paging?

Comment: @Prasath Paging is used for display and i already use jquery.dataTables for that purpose. When i execute such a query even with pagination then my firefox browser is flooded with tremendous data that it crashes. During such an operation I saw the memory usage of firefox in task manager and it turned out to be 1.1GB plus. So this is not supported by browser.

Comment: @SahilJariwala Still, do not do pagination in the browser, do it on the server. The datatables documentation does tell you how to use the server to paginate datatables: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html